# How do I make LibreOffice Writer use page numbers?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I've spent **an hour** now going through every single menu in the entire ***LibreOffice Writer*** program, and searching online. There is no way to set it to use page numbers. It lets you select which "style" should be used, and you can manually insert a "page number" into the normal text as a number (which is obviously not what we want), create an empty "footer", but nowhere does it let you set it to use page numbers.

This nonsensical page doesn't explain anything, yet uses many words: https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/swriter/guide/pagenumbers.html?DbPAR=WRITER

I refuse to believe that "there is no such feature". They must have just managed to hide it extremely well, both in the program and in the manual. Not only is this the most useful and basic feature imaginable for any word processor -- it's one of the easiest ones to implement as well. There is just no way that this isn't in the program. It **cannot possibly** be that they expect me to manually create a "footer" on every page and manually insert a page number from the menu, or type it in myself.

This is supposed to be a setting that you set for the document. Like a checkbox that you click, called "Use page numbers", and then it will show a "1" in the centre-bottom of the first page, "2" on the next, etc. If this "feature" truly is missing, I'm officially giving up entirely and forever on open source/free software.

Comment: `This is supposed to be a setting that you set for the document.`

I'm not sure why you think that, but it's not how it works. If there is a title page, then you need to decide whether to show the page number and whether it counts as the first page. Likewise, there may be a table of contents or other front material. There are also many different kinds of formatting in headers and footers, such as "page vi of xii." Only you, as the author, can make those decisions - the software cannot guess what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You already have all the pieces ("Create footer" and "Insert page number").

1. Click just below the bottom margin, but before the end of page
2. Scroll down and press "+" after "Footer (Default Style)"
3. Press tab twice to right align text (optional)
4. Press "Insert" then "Page Number"

The linked page has correct steps:

1. "Insert - Header and Footer - Footer - (name of page style)"
2. "Choose Insert - Field - Page Number to insert a page number"

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer to this is a bit more convoluted, but it will result what you want.

1. Format -> page style (default shortcut key: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Footer tab -> check the "footer on" checkbox.
3. Click "Same content on left and right page" and "Same content on first page" check-boxes if needed.

Now each of the pages of your document should have a footer. They will be kept "identical".

4. Click on the footer. On the right hand side at its top a button hiding a drop-down menu should appear.
5. Select insert page number from that menu.

A page number will appear on the left side of each footer.

You will notice that each page now has a footer, with automatically increasing page numbers. If you want other stuff in the footer, you definitely can have that without affecting the page numbering. By default, stuff you enter in one footer this way, will be exactly the same in all the other footers.

In case you want part of your document have different numbering styles (for example starting with roman numerals and then it becoming Arabic numbers, you can by working with page styles. This is, however, its own can of worms.

More information here: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/pagenumbers.html

Answer (score 1):

To put page numbers in the footer when you don't have a Footer, you have to first create the Footer.  Click on Insert - Header & Footer - Footer - Default Page Style.  Also click to make a check mark next to Use Header Footer Menu.

If the Footer already exists  with the Header Footer menu, skip the above and start here.
Click on the Footer.  On the right will appear a menu titled Footer Default page style.  Click on the down arrow to the right of these words.  From the drop down menu, click on Insert Page Number.
If a number appears, you're done, assuming you want the first page to be numbered "1."
If the words Page Number appear, you have one more task.  This is the tip in the link in your question above.  Click on View - Field Names and the number of the page will replace the words.

The Field Names is a labelling function and you have turned it off so that page numbers themselves show.

Comment: Does this add anything over the answers already given?

Comment: No other answer says anything about the Field Names function, and if it is on, you don't get page numbers.  You get the words "page number."  You never had this problem?  I spent two years without page numbers because no one pointed out the Field Names aspect of it.